# How to avoid errors happen when an obj is not existing in object.keys?

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck now I want to used `Object.keys(myobject).length` to check if this object is empty or length is zero But when `myobjects` is `undefiend` my conditional will send errors

> TypeError: can't convert undefined to object

To client browser and stop work any more so I want to get any idea to avoid this cause.

This is JavaScript conditional

```
if(Object.keys(myobject).length === 0 ) {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check if the `myobject` is Object and then use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) on it.

```
if (typeof myobject === 'object' && Object.keys(myobject).length === 0) {
```

OR

```
if (Object.keys(myobject || {}).length === 0) {
```

Comment: Thanks, How can you know that?